# How do I level up new heroes in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

I have pulled some new heroes from a recent banner, but the story quest I am trying to do has level 49 enemies.

When using my 'best' team, they are not strong enough and just die all the time. I've tried lots of different team combinations, and have died every time.

What effective techniques can I use to level up my lower level heroes? As fighting level 50 enemies at level 1 is not working for me and is ruining my enjoyment of the game, as I feel stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You should use exp books to level up your characters.

In Genshin Impact, the primary way to advance character level is to use experience books (Hero's Wit, Adventurer's Experience, and Wanderer's Advice). You get them either as rewards from quests and then later mainly as rewards for completing leylines, these are the blue cloud icons on the map. Killing monsters gives only a mostly negligible amount of exp.

For all of the methods to gain character exp see the [fandom-wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Character_EXP):

> Character EXP gained from quests, defeating enemies, and claiming Boss rewards is given to each member of your party, regardless of participation. Dead party members will still receive Character EXP. Characters not in your active party will not receive Character EXP.

To use exp books go to your character (press c on pc) and click on "level-up." You will need to ascend them to gain further progress.

You gain experience rewards from collecting boss/leyline rewards with the active team. This means that you can switch away from your active max-level main team to a different team low-level team and collect the rewards with it, netting you a small but steady exp-gain from challenges that your second team couldn't have finished.

### Other considerations.

Not only do you need to keep up with character levels, but you should also level the weapons and artefacts that they are using and the talents of your characters. These affect your character-strength **more** than the character levels.

Comment: So I can't use my new heroes until I have enough books to level them up? That would make new heroes not worth picking up to me

Comment: @DavidYell Correct. A lot of the game loop is managing your daily resin to get the resources that enable new characters/builds. Early on, you will have more characters than resources. You can swap around some of your weapons and artefacts between characters, but with continuous play, you can eventually have many dedicated builds and characters. The game is pretty good at steadily supplying you with extra resources that you can acquire in events.

Comment: @DavidYell But you also don't necessarily need levelled characters in every situation - a level one character can destroy an elemental shield as well as a level 90 character with some minor caveats. It takes some time to figure out what you should prioritise :)

Comment: @DavidYell New Heroes are always welcomed in my book, despite already having a character with the same element leveled up and ascended. Characters are designed differently, and some could provide advantages another character could not

Comment: Worth noting for future readers that I went back to Mondstat and the enemies were lv37 instead of lv50, making them easier to level on for a new team